# Why excel delete all the pasted hyperlinks, if I later removed any hyperlink from any one of them?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am using the below code to copy hyperlink from one cell to a range.
The hyperlinks have been pasted and working as it should, 
But if I later removed any hyperlink from any one of pasted hyperlinks ,then all hyperlinks from destination cells are deleted !! 
This issue happens either I have used vba (copy, paste & delete) or used merely excel. 
I am using office 2016.

```
Sub Hyperlinks_Issue()
 
    Range("R2").Copy Range("N2:N15")
 
    Range("N2").Hyperlinks.Delete
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that `Range("R2").Copy Range("N2:N15")` attaches the hyperlink in `R2` to the entire range of `N2:N15`. You can check this by inserting the following code immediately afterwards:

`Debug.Print (Range("N2:N15").Hyperlinks.Count)`

This returns `1`, meaning the entire range only has one hyperlink (instead of 14, as you might be expecting). If then you check this:

`Debug.Print (Range("N2").Hyperlinks(1).Range.Address)`

You will see that it returns `$N$2:$N$15`. Hence, when you use `Range("N2").Hyperlinks.Delete`, you are simply deleting the *one* hyperlink that is attached to the entire range.

To avoid this, loop through all the cells in your destination range and attach the hyperlink for each cell individually. E.g.

```
Sub copyHyperlinks()

For Each myCell In Range("N2:N15")

    Range("R2").Copy myCell

Next myCell

Debug.Print (Range("N2:N15").Hyperlinks.Count) '= 14

End Sub
```

Now, `Range("N2").Hyperlinks.Delete` will only delete the hyperlink in this particular cell.